# The limit of an alternating series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The sum of $(-1)^n \frac{\ln n}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40998/the-sum-of-1n-frac-ln-nn)

Compute 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}{\ln{k}}}{k}$$

Comment: What is "n" in the log's argument?

Comment: @EricNaslund I was just wondering why you didn't close this since it is an exact duplicate as you have pointed out in your comment.

Comment: @Marvis: Done.  In the past, there was some discussion about whether or not moderators should use their binding votes to close exact duplicates.  (Notably several meta threads)  I was just making sure at least one or two other member of the community agreed with closing.

Comment: @EricNaslund Ok. Yes it makes sense that the moderators wait for at-least another person to vote for closing a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider, for $s>1$, the following auxiliary convergent series:
$$
   \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\log(k)}{k^s} = -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} s} \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{k^s}= -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} s}\left( (2^{1-s} - 1)\zeta(s) \right)
$$
The value of the series in question is obtained as a limit:
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\log(k)}{k} = \lim_{s \searrow 1} \left( 2^{1-s} \log(2) \zeta(s) + \zeta^\prime(s) (1-2^{1-s}) \right)
$$
Since $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} + \gamma + \mathcal{O}(s-1)$, and $\zeta^\prime(s) = -\frac{1}{(s-1)^2} + \mathcal{O}(1)$ we arrive at:
$$
   \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\log(k)}{k} = \gamma \log(2) - \frac{\log^2(2)}{2}
$$