# Infinite series for Euler-Mascheroni constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory

## Problem

Show that
$$
\gamma = \tfrac 12 \log 2 + {1 \over \log 2} \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n {\log n \over n}.
$$

## Progress

I tried writing the terms $1/k$ of the harmonic sum in the definition of $\gamma$ as $\int_0^1 x^{k-1} dx$, and interchanging the order of summation and integration. This gives
$$
\gamma = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 {1 - x^n - \log n + x \log n \over 1 - x} dx,
$$
which might just be a dead end. I also know the alternate form
$$
\gamma = \lim_{s \to 1} {\zeta'(s) \over \zeta(s)} +  {1 \over s-1} = \lim_{s \to 1} -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda(n) n^{-s} + {1 \over s-1},
$$
but I don't see how it could help.

Notes: $\log x$ is the natural logarithm, $\Lambda(n)$ is the von Mangoldt function.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40998/the-sum-of-1n-frac-ln-nn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problem is from analysis book: Problems In Mathematical Analysis I Page (70)

[image]

[image]